# Mobilefirst Platform Foundation v8.0 development license vs Production license

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Can anyone knows what are the limitations in development version of Mobilefirst Platform foundation v8.0 (devkit)?

Is there any user limitations?

What is the difference between devkit version and production licensed version of MFP v8.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The devkit is meant only for development purposes and not production use. Devkit contains most of the salient features of mobilefirst.The devkit comes with a built in derby database, with space limitations. So you cannot use traditional backend commercial databases recommended for production like db2 or oracle. There will also be an issue with storing resources such as adapters that are large in size.

The mobilefirst server in the devkit is a liberty server. You will be unable to build a server farm with liberty servers in the devkit. Such liberty farms or wasnd clusters available in the production license version will enable you to scale the number of requests handled by your mobilefirst server. Thus scalibility ,load-balancing, high availability etc are available only with the production version. Hope this helps.